# Expanding website file display ---------show files in full format

Tags: visualization, files-and-directories, web-access, web

Many times looking for some material I find websites that seem to use a format that does not allow the file name to be fully visible.
You download the file that you think it is and it turns out that it was another file nothing to do.
It is possible to implement with mathematics a code that allows me to see the full name of the files and be able to download them just as you do with the browser, by clicking on them.

bad example

https://www.colegiosantodomingo.cl/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/*

good example

[https://www.ime.usp.br/~manuelg/arquivos/Algebra/](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Emanuelg/arquivos/Algebra/)

Thanks

Comment: In the Google Chrome browser I can see the full path in the lower left corner if I hover the link with the mouse.

Comment: @C. E.,thanks ,the problem is that I see a lot of pages when I search for material and that way would be extremely slow,

Comment: I was looking at a glance of all the files, which are hundreds at times.